# Speed type tester - how to reference variables out of scope?

Tags: python, function, datetime, scope, object-oriented-analysis

I am relatively new to python and I am struggling with building this speed type tester, I am not sure as to why I can seem to change the value of ''time_over'' from false to true in the first function, but can't seem to change the 'text' variable from being empty to get the string I am trying to pass through the input and feed it to the 'counter' function.

I don't want to look up for solutions online as I am sure that there are thousand of speed type testers written in Python, so I tried to focus on building separate functions that have a specific task, trying to divide the problem into smaller parts. Please be kind, I'm only a newbie!

```
import time


def start_timer():
    """Starts the timer // returns (time_over = True) if timer hits 0"""
    time_over = False

    for secs in range(60, -1, -1):
        time.sleep(1)
        if secs == 30:
            print('Time remaining:', secs)
        elif secs == 10:
            print('Time remaining:', secs)
        elif secs == 0:
            time_over = True
            print('@@@ Ding Ding Ding, time is over champ! @@@')

    return time_over


def counter(some_string):
    """Counts the characters in a given string or list"""
    total_chars = len(some_string)
    print(f'You typed {total_chars} in total, wow!')


print('You will have 1 minute to write as many words as possible')
start_question = input('type y when you are ready or n to exit.').lower()
if start_question == 'y':
    start_timer()
    text = ''
    while not start_timer:

        text = input()

    if start_timer:

        counter(text)
```

Comment: You don't move past the line `start_timer()` until the timer hits zero, so you'll never enter the `while no start_timer` block

Comment: You seem to expect your `start_timer` function to run in parallel to other parts of your programs. This is not the case. You need to use `threading` if you want two parts of your program to run in parallel. Additionally, your input function will only return if the user presses enter.